# Changing built in account to Local System programmatically in sql server

Tags: sql, account, built-in, programmatically-created

I want to programmatically change built in account to local system of SQL Server 2008 R2.
It will be executed in stored procedure.

I couldn't find any information.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you mean to say "change the SQL Server service startup account".

**Manually** follow the procedure described at [Change the Service Startup Account for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345578.aspx). There is no supported programmatic way. You cannot do it in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

yes i know this way but i have to do that.
when i try execute this code

```
ALTER DATABASE db_stock SET READ_WRITE;
```

My project give me errors that are about

> Operating system error 5: Access is denied.

So I have to change startup account programmatically.

Do you know how I can solve this problem with other ways?